# jQuery: Call two functions on one event and one selector and pass data between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, function, call

How can i call two functions on the same selector and one event and pass data between them ?
The first function is .hover which

```
 $("#cartItems tr.cItem").hover(
   function ()
   {
       receipt = $(this).next().children().text();
       //I want to pass receipt value to second function
   },
   function()
   {

   }
 )
```

and the second function is:

```
$("#cartItems tr.cItem").qtip(
{
   content: receipt, // i need to pass it here
   show: 'mouseover',
   hide: 'mouseout'
});
```

it is tooltip that pops up "contet" value in small window

How can I call / merge this two functions together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to wait until the element is hovered to call `qtip`, the `qtip` plug-in is meant to be called to *set up* hovering behavior.

If the content you want in the qtip exists as of when you're doing this, this may be what you want:

```
$("#cartItems tr.cItem").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.qtip({
        content: {
            text: $this.next().children().text()
        }
    });
});
```

That sets up the qtips **once**, with the text derived from the next element's child content.

If you want to do that dynamically (e.g., the next element's child content may change as the user does things on the page), then:

```
$("#cartItems tr.cItem").mouseenter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.qtip("option", "content.text", $this.next().children().text());
}).qtip();
```

That sets up the qtips (once), and sets up a `mouseenter` handler that sets the qtip text when the mouse actually enters the element.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Your first solution is exactly what I needed. The content of next().children() is already on the page and is static and hidden (display:none) and I'm passing it to popup window. Thank You very much.